# Is there any biological basis for the commonplace "eyes popping out" cartoon?

Tags: human-eye

We might all be familiar with images like these below:

[image]

[image]

I see this clearly "works" in a cartoon context. It makes a point. That "eyeballs" hanging outside belong to the individual and can be shown next to him and not in the floor or so. But, **is there any biological basis for this?** Is something like this ever possible? Probably the answer is no, as the (optic) nerve connecting the brain with the "eyeball" surely cannot be extended like that. Would the eyeball actually hold its shape?

PS: for the sensitive among the crowd (including myself), please do not post gore-like pictures to show what actually happens. If want to provide some visuals, diagrams might suffice.

Comment: I once saw a guy in "Ripley's believe it or not" who could pop his eyes out to some extent (not till the optic nerve is visible).

Comment: Also, see [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXQCKxKgoaA). What extent of eye popping are you asking about? Usually, in cartoons eye popping is associated with an extremely delightful visual stimulus. Are you asking if such a thing happens in real life?

Comment: @WYSIWYG "What extent of eye popping are you asking about?" Well, that's probably an important part of the answer. If this is ever possible to any extent, or if actually it doesn't work that way at all. E.g. optic nerve cannot be extended and so can ever be visible.